# Excel 2010 Formula not working - SUM IF

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have this excel table and I want to SUM some values from a column depending on what value they have on the column to the left.

The values from the right that have "Overall Results" on the left, are the ones that I need to SUM.

I have tried some conditionals but none of them work, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Your title states "formula not working". What formula have you tried?

Comment: It was a very similar formula to the one douglaspls posted, but I wasn't entering the sum_range correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

=SUMIF(`Cells on the left`;"Overall results";`Cells on the right`)

Check this example:[image]

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5;"Overall results";B1:B5)
```

Note: As mentioned by @CharlieRB you should used comma `,` instead of semicolon `;` depending on you region.

Comment: Your formula will not work with `;`. It needs to have `,` (commas).

Comment: @CharlieRB I *think* it depends on the (geographical) region in which excel is being used. In some regions i believe, ";" is the default delimiter in a formula as opposed to ",".

Comment: @Jaycal is correct. It depends on your region. Do you think I should still change it to commas?

Comment: At least make a note of it in your answer in case someone is not in the same region as you (like me). Good answer, by the way!

Comment: I was having this problem! I'm in Argentina, I have Office in English, and the computer language in Spanish, in all that mess I have to use ","

Comment: Also, what If I have another criteria to SUM? I mean two criterias "Overall results" and "Income" ?

Comment: That is a different formula; `SUMIFS`. It can not be answered in this question so you can either look it up or ask another question.